# GIT pushing to multiple remotes

Tags: git, github

I have two repositories for the same project but with different collaborators and I need to be able to push and pull from one remote to another. Example:

**Origin** -> github.com/myrepo

**Bitbucket** -> bitbucket.com/myrepo

So I want to be able to create a branc, push it to remote **Bitbucket** have the collaborators working there and once is done pull it to my local, review it and push it to remote **Origin**

I tried just adding the second remote and doing git push Bitbucket  but for some reason it tries to push a lot of files

Comment: Can you elaborate? what did you pull and from where? what did it try to push?
I often work with two remotes when I want to be able to update my fork of some repo, and I pull from the repo and push to my fork and it works fine.

Comment: For example let's say I create a branch for a new functionality from my local, so I push it to Bitbucket remote, then a collaborator starts working on it and once is ready I have to pull it, review it in my local and if is fine I have to push it to my Origin

Comment: Ok. Does `git pull Bitbucket` followed by `git push` not work?
In general, if you're on some branch `branch` and want to pull from `remoteA` and push to `remoteB`, then `git pull remoteA branch` followed by `git push remoteB` should do what you want.

Comment: That's how I was trying to do it but I Found really weird it starting pushing a lot of files when I did the first push of the new branch from my local to Bitbucket remote. 

Is that something expected?

Comment: If that branch didnt previously exist in the remote, then yes - it was simply pushing all of the files that belong to the branch you branched off of in addition to the new files

Answer (score 0):

If you're on some branch branch and want to `pull` from `remoteA` and `push` to `remoteB`, then `git pull remoteA branch` followed by `git push remoteB` should do what you want.

The additional files you saw being pushed were probably just the files that belong to the branch you branched off of: since from what I understand from your question neither the original branch nor the new branch exist in remoteB - all of their files/commits have to be pushed too.